# DOB select boxes on Magento registration form

Tags: magento

I'm currently using Magento 1.5.0.1

When a customer reigisters on the registration page (/account/create), he has to insert a date of birth (dob).

By default, the date of birth consists of 3 text-boxes. I have modified the file at /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget.

So, instead of text-boxes there are now 3 select-boxes where the user can select a date

However, when all information is filled in correctly and you click on the "submit" button nothing happens (no errors, messages or anything).

Any idea on how to make the "submit" button work again?

Thanks

Edit:

The id's of the  are the same as the one's used by the "". I've posted the code that I have changed

I've made 2 functions that print the options's element:

```
function getOptions($minValue, $maxValue)
```

{
    $options = "";

```
for ($count = $minValue; $count <= $maxValue; $count++)
{
    $options = $options . '<option value="' . $count . '">' . $count . '</option>';
}

return $options;
```

}

```
function getYears()
```

{
    $years = "";
    $currentYear = date('Y');

```
for ($count = 1900; $count <= $currentYear; $count++)
{
    $years = $years . '<option value="' . $count;

    if ($count == '1980')
    {
        $years = $years . '" selected="selected"';  
    }

    $years = $years .  '">' . $count . '</option>';
}

return $years;
```

}

And i've changed the input type=text to select

```
$this->setDateInput('d',
'<div class="dob-day">
<label for="' . $this->getFieldId('day') . '">' . $this->__('DD') . '</label>
<select id="' . $this->getFieldId('day') . '" name="' . $this->getFieldName('day') . '" title="' . $this->__('Day') . '" class="validate-select" ' . $this->getFieldParams() . '>' . getOptions(1,31) . '

</select>
</div>
<br />');

$this->setDateInput('m',
    '<div class="dob-month">
<label for="' . $this->getFieldId('month') . '">' . $this->__('MM') . '</label>
         <select id="' . $this->getFieldId('month') . '" name="' . $this->getFieldName('month') . '" title="' .  $this->__('Month') . '" class="validate-select"' . $this->getFieldParams() . '>' . getOptions(1,12) . '

</select>
</div>
<br />');

$this->setDateInput('y',
    '<div class="dob-year">
<label for="' . $this->getFieldId('year') . '">' . $this->__('YYYY') . '</label>
        <select id="' . $this->getFieldId('year') . '" name="' . $this->getFieldName('year') . '" title="' . $this->__('Year') . '" class="validate-select"' . $this->getFieldParams() . '>' . getYears() . '
     </div>'
);
```

Comment: Does the `<select>`'s have the same id's as the previous `<input type="text"...` ? If they do, the only possible chance would be the getting value.

Comment: paste your template code , best bet is that your validation fails silently

Comment: any errors in javascript console?

Comment: Yes there is an error in de javascript console. I've never noticed it before.
Anyway it says:
On Line 425 of js.js ==> this.day.addClassName('validate-custom');
this.day is undefined

Comment: Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz replace the dob.phtml in 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/

to follwing code  and override new field to old with the help of css

```
/////////////////////////////

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob')
   ->setDate($this->getCustomer()->getDob())
   ->toHtml() ?>

// For checkout/onepage/billing.phtml:

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob')
   ->setDate($this->getCustomer()->getDob())
   ->setFieldIdFormat('billing:%s')
   ->setFieldNameFormat('billing[%s]')
   ->toHtml() ?>

/* NOTE: Regarding styles - if we leave it this way, we'll move it to boxes.css
      Alternatively we could calculate widths automatically using block input parameters.
*/

/**
 * @see Mage_Customer_Block_Widget_Dob
 */
<label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('month')?>"<?php if ($this->isRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('Date of Birth') ?></label>
<div class="input-box customer-dob">
<?php
    $this->setDateInput('d',
        '<div class="dob-day">
             <input type="text" id="' . $this->getFieldId('day') . '" name="' . $this->getFieldName('day') . '" value="' . $this->getDay() . '" title="' . $this->__('Day') . '" class="input-text validate-custom" ' . $this->getFieldParams() . '  />
             <label for="' . $this->getFieldId('day') . '">' . $this->__('DD') . '</label>
         </div>'
    );?>


    <select name="nday" id="nday" onchange="getElementById('<?php echo $this->getFieldId('day');?>').value=this.value" style="width:90px;">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php
    for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
    {
    echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>

    <select name="nmon" id="nmon" onchange="getElementById('<?php echo $this->getFieldId('month');?>').value=this.value" style="width:90px;">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
    <?php echo '<option value="">'.$this->__("Select").'</option>'.'<option value="01">'.$this->__("January").'</option>'.'<option value="02">'.$this->__("February").'</option>'.'<option value="03">'.$this->__("March").'</option>'.'<option value="04">'.$this->__("April").'</option>'.'<option value="05">'.$this->__("May").'</option>'.'<option value="06">'.$this->__("June").'</option>'.'<option value="07">'.$this->__("July").'</option>'.'<option value="08">'.$this->__("August").'</option>'.'<option value="09">'.$this->__("September").'</option>'.'<option value="10">'.$this->__("October").'</option>'.'<option value="11">'.$this->__("November").'</option>'.'<option value="12">'.$this->__("December").'</option>'; ?>
    </select>


    <select name="nyear" id="nyear" onchange="getElementById('<?php echo $this->getFieldId('year');?>').value=this.value" style="width:90px;">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php
    for($j=date('Y')-80;$j<=date('Y');$j++)
    {
    echo "<option value='".$j."'>".$j."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </p>
    <?php

    $this->setDateInput('m',
        '<div class="dob-month">
             <input type="text" id="' . $this->getFieldId('month') . '" name="' . $this->getFieldName('month') . '" value="' . $this->getMonth()  . '" title="' . $this->__('Month')  . '" class="input-text validate-custom" ' . $this->getFieldParams()  . '/>
             <label for="' . $this->getFieldId('month') . '">' . $this->__('MM')  . '</label>
         </div>'
    );





    $this->setDateInput('y',
        '<div class="dob-year">
             <input type="text" id="' . $this->getFieldId('year') . '" name="' . $this->getFieldName('year') . '" value="' . $this->getYear()  . '" title="' . $this->__('Year')  . '" class="input-text validate-custom" ' . $this->getFieldParams()  . ' />
             <label for="' . $this->getFieldId('year') . '">' . $this->__('YYYY')  . '</label>
         </div>'
    );

?>




    <?php echo $this->getSortedDateInputs() ?>
    <div class="dob-full" style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('dob')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('dob')?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="validation-advice" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var customer_dob = new Varien.DOB('.customer-dob', <?php echo $this->isRequired() ? 'true' : 'false' ?>, '<?php echo $this->getDateFormat() ?>');
//]]>
</script>

////////////////////////////
```

it work fine .this is just an idea.......
enjoy

Comment: Please edit your post to format the code correctly. Either indent by 4 spaces or use the `{}` button that is provided.

Comment: I ended up doing it, but I would encourage you to do in future, @Vinod Kumar.

Comment: @Vinod Kumar: Works great, except you forgot the quotes by the onchange events: should be: getElementById('<?php echo $this->getFieldId('month');?>')

Answer (score 2):

Replace/create dob.phtml file located in app/design/frontend/[package-name]/default/template/customer/widget/

https://gist.github.com/ncla/7794502 (tested on Magento 1.8 community edition)

Accepted answer might work, but hiding inputs seems unacceptable. Also setDateInput, getSortedDateInputs methods are unnecessary, as you pass them HTML just to get them back.

If you try converting dob.phtml from input boxes to drop down boxes, Magento form validation will fail (throw JS error) because it can't find "day" input. So I just override Varien.DOB initialize function to select correct elements.

Answer (score 1):

Thats how I did it. Maybe someone can use it

1. Grab the dob code from some [site](http://www.endreywalder.com/blog/change-date-of-birth-field-to-select-boxes-in-magento/) or from Magento default theme
2. Create your own widget template in your theme folder, for example `customer/widget/dob-custom.phtml`
3. Call this widget in your template file, for example

   ```
   echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob')->setTemplate('customer/widget/dob-custom.phtml')->toHtml();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I think is because the format of the DD is not correct. You are generating a day like 1, 2, 3, 4... while it should be 01, 02, 03, 04,.. etc..

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I recently switched from ncla's solution to this:
http://www.endreywalder.com/blog/change-date-of-birth-field-to-select-boxes-in-magento/

Instead of displaying 01-12 for months, this will output the actual names which I like much better.

Tested on Magento 1.9.2